# Убрать checked с потомков input[type=checkbox]

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как сделать так, чтоб при выборе страны снималось выделение со всех соответствующих городов и наоборот, при выборе города снималось выделение со страны, если оно установлено.

Пробовал так, но тогда, если отмечены города, мне не дает отметить страну и снять выделение с городов.

```
$('body').on('change','.box.country .item ul .country-name', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this)
      .closest(".box.country .item ul ul li")
      .find('input[type=checkbox]')
      .prop('checked', '');
  }
  if ($(".box.country .item ul ul li input[type=checkbox]").is(':checked')) {
    $(this)
      .closest(".box.country .item ul")
      .find('.country-name input[type=checkbox]')
      .prop('checked', '');
  }
});
```

```css
.box.country.active {
  max-height: 100vh;
  visibility: visible;
}
.box.country .item {
  max-width: 25%;
  -webkit-flex-basis: 25%;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 25%;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccd6e6;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccd6e6;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-content: center;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
  align-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.box.country .item>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.box.country .item>ul>li {
  color: #454545;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.box.country .item>ul .country-name {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-content: center;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
  align-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.box.country .item>ul>li ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.box.country .item>ul>li ul li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #454545;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<div class="box country active">
  <div class="item">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="country-name">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" checked="checked" id="country_1" value="RU">
            <label for="country_1">Россия</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" id="city_1" value="1"> 
              <label for="city_1">Москва</label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" id="city_2" value="2"> 
              <label for="city_2">Санкт-Петербург</label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" id="city_3" value="3"> 
              <label for="city_3">Великий Новгород</label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" id="city_4" value="4"> 
              <label for="city_4">Оренбург</label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" id="city_5" value="5"> 
              <label for="city_5">Екатеринбург</label>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="country-name">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" checked="checked" id="country_2" value="UA">
            <label for="country_2">Украина</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" id="city_6" value="6"> 
              <label for="city_6">Киев</label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" id="city_7" value="7"> 
              <label for="city_7">Харьков</label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" id="city_8" value="8"> 
              <label for="city_8">Одесса</label>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="country-name">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" checked="checked" id="country_3" value="BY">
            <label for="country_3">Белоруссия</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" id="city_9" value="9"> 
              <label for="city_9">Минск</label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" id="city_10" value="10"> 
              <label for="city_10">Гомель</label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" id="city_11" value="11"> 
              <label for="city_11">Гродно</label>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: прошу прощения, исправил

Comment: исправил, извиняюсь

Comment: На мой взгляд, это не то поведение, которое ожидал бы пользователь. Опишите в каком сценарии это используется. Если же к Вашей задаче, то добавляйте классы и data-атрибуты к элементам и при событии onchange проверяйте необходимые условия.

Comment: добавил в вопросе, как я делаю, но если я выбрал сперва страну и дальше выбираю города это страны, то с этой страны не снимается выделение, и ноборот, если выделены города и я нажал на страну этих городов, то страну нужно выделить с городов снять выделение

Comment: Сколько стран может быть выделено? Минимум одна? Могут быть выделены все? Только одна? P.S.: и кстати, у checkboх'ов не может быть потомков.

Comment: страны могут быть выделены все, потомки я имею ввиду по ul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Но я бы всё таки использовал какую-то привязку к классам и data-атрибутам.

```js
$('div.box')
  .on('change', ':checkbox', function(e) {

  var $checkbox = $(e.target),
      isCountry = $checkbox.closest('li').has('ul').length > 0;

  if (isCountry) {
    $.each($checkbox.closest('li').find('ul :checkbox'), function(idx, itm){
     itm.checked = false;
    });
  }
  else {
    $checkbox
    .closest('ul')
    .closest('li')
    .find('.country-name :checkbox')
    .prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```css
.box.country.active {
  visibility: visible;
}
.box.country .item {
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccd6e6;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccd6e6;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.box.country .item>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.box.country .item>ul>li {
  color: #454545;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.box.country .item>ul .country-name {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.box.country .item>ul>li ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.box.country .item>ul>li ul li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #454545;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box country active">
  <div class="item">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="country-name">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" checked="checked" id="country_1" value="RU">
            <label for="country_1">Россия</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" id="city_1" value="1"> 
              <label for="city_1">Москва</label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" id="city_2" value="2"> 
              <label for="city_2">Санкт-Петербург</label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" id="city_3" value="3"> 
              <label for="city_3">Великий Новгород</label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" id="city_4" value="4"> 
              <label for="city_4">Оренбург</label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" id="city_5" value="5"> 
              <label for="city_5">Екатеринбург</label>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="country-name">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" checked="checked" id="country_2" value="UA">
            <label for="country_2">Украина</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" id="city_6" value="6"> 
              <label for="city_6">Киев</label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" id="city_7" value="7"> 
              <label for="city_7">Харьков</label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" id="city_8" value="8"> 
              <label for="city_8">Одесса</label>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="country-name">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" checked="checked" id="country_3" value="BY">
            <label for="country_3">Белоруссия</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" id="city_9" value="9"> 
              <label for="city_9">Минск</label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" id="city_10" value="10"> 
              <label for="city_10">Гомель</label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" id="city_11" value="11"> 
              <label for="city_11">Гродно</label>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```